# Creating a 30s timer display with SVG and JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am in the process of trying to create a 30s countdown timer display using SVG and a spot of JS.  The idea is simple

1. Draw the face of the countdown clock as an SVG circle
2. Inside it draw a closed SVG path in the form of the sector of circle
3. Use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to update that sector at one second intervals

My effort is shown below. While it works the final result is far from being smooth and convincing.

- When the spent time gets into the second quadrant of the circle the sector appears to swell past the circumference
- When it is in the third and fourth quadrant it appears to detach from the circumference.

What am I doing wrong here and how could it be improved?

```js
var _hold = {tickStart:0,stopTime:30,lastDelta:0};

String.prototype.format = function (args)
{
 var newStr = this,key;
 for (key in args) {newStr = newStr.replace('{' + key + '}',args[key]);}
 return newStr;
};

Boolean.prototype.intval = function(places)
{
 places = ('undefined' == typeof(places))?0:places; 
 return (~~this) << places;
};


function adjustSpent(timeStamp)
{
 if (0 === _hold.tickStart) _hold.tickStart = timeStamp;
 var delta = Math.trunc((timeStamp - _hold.tickStart)/1000);
 if (_hold.lastDelta < delta)
 {
  _hold.lastDelta = delta;
  var angle = 2*Math.PI*(delta/_hold.stopTime),
      dAngle = 57.2958*angle,
      cx = cy = 50,
      radius = 38,
      top = 12,
      x = cx + radius*Math.sin(angle),
      y = cy - radius*Math.cos(angle),
      large = (180 < dAngle).intval();
  
   var d = (360 <= dAngle)?"M50,50 L50,12 A38,38 1 0,1 51,12 z":"M50,50 L50,12 A38,38 1 {ll},1 {xx},{yy} z".format({ll:large,xx:x,yy:y});
   var spent = document.getElementById('spent');    
   if (spent) spent.setAttribute("d",d);
 }
 if (delta < _hold.stopTime) window.requestAnimationFrame(adjustSpent);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(adjustSpent);
```

```css
timer
{
 position:absolute;
 height:20vh;
 width:20vh;
 border-radius:100%;
 background-color:orange;
 left:calc(50vw - 5vh);
 top:15vh;
}

#clockface{fill:white;}
#spent{fill:#6683C2;}
```

```html
<timer>
     <svg width="20vh" height="20vh" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="38" id="clockface"></circle>
      <path d="M50,50 L50,12 A38,38 1 0,1 51,12 z" id="spent"></path>
     </svg>
    </timer>
```

Comment: Your arc command has a radius of 37, while you compute the endpoint with a radius of 38.

Comment: Full marks for spotting that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A posible solution would be using a stroke animation like this:

The blue circle has a radius of `38/2 = 19`

The `stroke-width` of the blue circle is 38 giving the illusion of a circle of 38 units.

Please take a look at the path: it's also a circle of radius = 19.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  height:90vh;
}
#clockface {
  fill: silver;
}
#spent {
  fill:none;
  stroke: #6683c2;
  stroke-width: 38px;
  stroke-dasharray: 119.397px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 119.397px;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}
  

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="38" id="clockface"></circle>
      <path d="M50,31 A19,19 1 0,1 50,69 A19,19 1 0,1 50,31" id="spent"></path>
     </svg>
```

In this case I've used css animations but you can control the value for `stroke-dashoffset` with JavaScript.

The value for `stroke-dasharray` was obtained using `spent.getTotalLength()`

If you are not aquainted with stroke animations in SVG please read [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Comment: Thank you for this - I always prefer solutions that do not require scripting.  The animation is smoother but that could just be down to the fact that my 1s animation interval is too big.

Comment: Simple and great solution! It support transparency on moving pie chart!